# String data in list to numeric values in python | unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, categorical-data

I have a list as follows, it's a huge list, this is just a chunk of it.

```
 my_list= [['I. R. Palmer','U. Kersten'],
           ['H. Breitwieser', 'U. Kersten'],
           ['Halvard Skogsrud', 'Boualem Benatallah', 'Fabio Casati', 'Manh Q. Dinh'],
           ['Stefano Ceri', 'Piero Fraternali', 'Stefano Paraboschi']]
```

I want to assign each string in list a unique numeric value. if a string is repeating some where else, assign It the same previous value

```
new_list= [[0,1],
           [2,1],
           [3,4,5,6],
           [7,8,9]]
```

i have tried

```
pd.factorize(my_list)
```

but i am getting

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten list, use `factorize` working with 1d array, create dict by `zip` and replace in nested list comprehension:

```
a = [y for x in my_list for y in x]
f1, f2 = pd.factorize(a)
d = dict(zip(f2[f1], f1))

new_list = [[d[y] for y in x] for x in my_list]
print (new_list)
[[0, 1], [2, 1], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.factorize` operates on a one-dimensional sequence, but you have a 2D sequence. And since your 2D sequence isn't a regular shape (each internal list has a different length) you can't work around that by reshaping. The error you are seeing is because pandas is trying to treat the internal lists as the categories rather than the strings inside the internal lists.

You could build the result yourself:

```
authors_map = {}  # I'm just guessing that they're authors
next_id = 0
new_list = []
for authors in my_list:
    new_authors = []
    for author in authors:
        if author not in authors_map:
            authors_map[author] = next_id
            next_id += 1
        new_authors.append(authors_map[author])
    new_list.append(new_authors)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have A 1-D sequence in `pd.factorize`. Refer [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.factorize.html)

You can use `np.concatenate` to convert list into 1D

```
import numpy as np
print(np.concatenate(my_list))
# array(['I. R. Palmer', 'U. Kersten', 'H. Breitwieser', 'U. Kersten',
#   'Halvard Skogsrud', 'Boualem Benatallah', 'Fabio Casati',
#   'Manh Q. Dinh', 'Stefano Ceri', 'Piero Fraternali',
#   'Stefano Paraboschi'], dtype='<U18')

print(pd.factorize(np.concatenate(my_list)))
```

Output:

```
(array([0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64),
 array(['I. R. Palmer', 'U. Kersten', 'H. Breitwieser', 'Halvard Skogsrud',
        'Boualem Benatallah', 'Fabio Casati', 'Manh Q. Dinh',
        'Stefano Ceri', 'Piero Fraternali', 'Stefano Paraboschi'],
       dtype=object))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.factorize.html) + [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) + [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html#numpy.cumsum) + [`array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html)

`pd.factorize` works by hashing. But the values in your lists *are* lists, which aren't hashable. Indeed, in any case, you aren't looking to hash lists but individual values.

Instead, you can factorize a *flattened* list and use an array of indices for splitting:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flattened = np.concatenate(my_list)
idx_split = np.array(list(map(len, my_list))).cumsum()[:-1]

res = [i.tolist() for i in np.array_split(pd.factorize(flattened)[0], idx_split)]

print(res)

[[0, 1], [2, 1], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```